# Log file not getting created using NLog when filename is set dynamically

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am using the below NLog configuration with FileName property removed. I want to set it dynamically. I have written the code for it as well. But it doesnt create the Log file at all at the specified location.

Please let me know if I am going wrong anywhere.

**NLog.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
      <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />

      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
           layout="${longdate} ${level} ${message}" archiveAboveSize="1048576"                
           concurrentWrites="true"
           keepFileOpen="false"
           encoding="iso-8859-2" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**C# Code to dynamically set filename**:

```
            LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
            FileTarget fileTarget = new FileTarget();
            config.AddTarget("logfile", fileTarget);
            fileTarget.FileName =  @"C:\Logfile\Log.txt"; 
            NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;

            LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
```

But log file Log.txt is not getting created at C:\Logfile>. No exception thrown as well

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I'm pretty sure that you are overwriting your configuration by code. Why don't you configure everything in code?</strike>

Are you sure that you have the necessary permissions to write to `C:\Logfile\Log.txt`?
I've just tried your code and it`s working for me.

You could also enable the internal logging of NLog: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for the setter for `NLog.LogManager.Configuration`, you will see that it has side-effects, presumably for performance reasons. I encountered a similar problem to you where I tried to mutate the logging configuration after it had been set earlier in the program, and found that my changes were not being respected.

For me, the solution was to create a new LoggingConfiguration object and assign that. In your case, simply moving the assignment will fix the problem:

```
LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
FileTarget fileTarget = new FileTarget();
config.AddTarget("logfile", fileTarget);
fileTarget.FileName =  @"C:\Logfile\Log.txt"; 

LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule); 

NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

I appreciate that I'm more than 3 years too late to solve the problem for you but perhaps this will help someone else.